# Remove front small side window in a 2014 Honda Civic

Tags: honda, civic, window

[image]

I have to remove tint on the my window. I've already removed the tint on the part that rolls up-and-down. Now I need to remove the tint on the little pane in the corner.

The front driver/passenger side windows - the ones that roll up and down - are relatively easy to remove the entire pane (Remove door panel, unscrew... insert panel, rescrew).

I haven't been able to find a good "how-to" remove/replace that front small window.

How do I remove it with the intention of simply putting it back in when done while keeping the trim and seal intact? (Or, possibly, replace the trim around the panel)

Comment: Is the intent just to remove and reapply the window tint? May be a lot easier to just leave it in place.

Comment: No, just remove tint. Came with car and state laws say I need a doctor's note to have it. Shoddy tint as well.

Comment: And if it's easier/recommended to keep in... That's a valid answer, imo... Just trying to see how it's done.

Comment: I cannot see your image, but I'm assuming you are talking about the window forward of the side view mirror. I've never dealt with the newer Civics before. Some vehicles it's relatively easy to remove the side glass ... others it's just a lot easier to leave it alone. Hopefully someone with some experience with it can give you a qualified answer.

Comment: I have tints on the rear windows - but two have been damaged and they don't seem to be "glued" in the normal sense of the term, so you could try neatly cutting with a very sharp knife around the edge and peeling it off the surface...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an aftermarket tint, then remove it in place.  Best to use plastic razor blades.  They won't scratch the glass.  You still have to be careful, but they are perfect for this task.  [Here is a sample.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004623NU2) Reminder, most all of the aftermarket tint is applied in place without removing any glass.  Its much harder to install the stuff, then it is to remove it.  But to make it easy for you and not damage anything, use the plastic razor blades.  I suspect a regular hair dryer might assist you along the way.  (NOT a commercial paint remover heat gun -- way too hot!)

[image: plastic razor blades]

On the other hand, the question you've asked is how to remove the small window.  To do that you have to remove the glass rubber/steel surround.  First put the glass down in the track.  Next remove the door trim panel, then remove all the bolts that hold the surround in.  Then remove the surround.  Once the door glass surround is removed, you will be able to see exactly how the small glass is held in place...

This isn't exactly your model year, but you can get a glimpse on how the stuff is installed.

[image: Door glass surround and trim]

Recommendation: Check out a Chilton's or Haynes manual for your vehicle. $30 USD well spent.  That will tell exactly how to remove the door trim panel without messing anything up or cracking plastic anywhere.

Edit:  I just realized you want to remove AND reinstall the window tint. I have to say, there is no way to compete with the very cheap price the shops here charge for the install. There is definitely an art to this, and those guys to 10 or 15 cars each day every day.  They are truly experts.  I happen to live in Las Vegas, and a large number of cars here get tint because of it's sunload blocking properties (to reduce Air Conditioning cooling load.)  Maybe its time for a mini-vacation to Vegas, or Tucson or Phoenix?

Comment: No, I just want to remove the tint and reinstall the window sans tint and without damaging and having to replace anything. I wanted to know if I could remove the glass to do like I did with the main panels - peel and scrub with soap and water. I'll reword the question to clarify, but I think you hit the main points.

Comment: CD, it can be removed by pulling out the panel. Keep a small quantity of silicone paste handy to put on those black rubber lines.